# Nuxt: How to create a reusable function that implements another nuxt module?

Tags: nuxt.js

Goal:
Create a reusable function that logs errors and sends errors to sentry via the sentry module (@nuxtjs/sentry).

Questions:
1. Should I create this reusable module as a plugin, module or in the utils directory?
2. How do I access @nuxt/sentry from within the plugin, module or util file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@nuxtjs/sentry](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sentry-module) exposes `$sentry` object in context of Vue instances, [Nuxt Context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) object and Store (*this info will eventually end up in documentation but for now you can look at this [pull request](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sentry-module/pull/85) to see a bit more information, including examples*).

Once you have access to that object, you can just call `$sentry.captureException` API to report an error. If you want to have your own reusable function that will call that API, I would recommend creating a Nuxt plugin so that you can [inject](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#combined-inject) your function in same places where `$sentry` object is available.

Comment: how do I access the `$sentry` object from within the plugin?

Comment: It's injected to `context.app` (`context.app.$sentry`) by the `@nuxtjs/sentry`

Comment: @rchl I am trying to create plugin like this

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    inject('myInjectedFunction', string => {
        console.log('That was easy!', string, app.$sentry);
    })
}

but i am getting undefined, though i have added module in nuxt config.